# Responsive background css images

Tags: html, ios, css

I'm trying to make my background image on my splash page resize to smaller sizes. I want the image to cover the entire section whatever size screen it may be.

```
.splash{
background-image: url("../images/lanternboys_medium.jpg");
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding-bottom: 40px;}
```

When I view this on my ipad the picture is huge! I've read that others have tried removing the height and width and set background size as "contain" but it doesn't stretch to what I want without the "cover" function.

The current size of the picture is 1366x911 but I do have a larger size of 5184x3456.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, vw and vh units doesn't work properly on iOS devices. Maybe if you set your background height to 100% and the background width to auto? Since your height is smaller than the width, it should do the trick.

Comment: Now the page below has moved upwards and the splash page is now only 60px.

Comment: We'll need an exemple then. Can you send us a link to your website?